# Unable to find incomplete job in HTML

Tags: java, php, html

I have completed `HTML` project and works find and no **ERROR**

Now my problem is that I am unable to find incomplete job in my Project. I use **Netbeans** for creating this project is there a way to find any incomplete work in existing project?

I used `HTML, Flash, java,` to create this entire project. Is there a tool to find this incomplete work or can I find it using Netbeans
So, how do I find incomplete work?

Thanks in advance

### CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Atomic Structure and Chemical Bonds</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/VLAB.css' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/E20.css' />

    <!--<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' />-->


    <!--for Font-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/fonts/webfontkit_proximaNova_reg/ProximaNova-Regular.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/fonts/webfontkit_proximanova_sb/ProximaNova-Semibold.css" />




    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.shuffle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/calc.js"></script>


<!-- Icon Assets -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/journal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/sound.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/print.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function incrementButtons( upBtn, downBtn, qtyField )
{
var step = parseFloat( qtyField.value ) || 1,
currentValue = step;

downBtn.onclick = function()
{
currentValue = parseFloat( qtyField.value ) || step; 
qtyField.value = ( currentValue -= Math.min( step, currentValue - step ) );
}

upBtn.onclick = function()
{
currentValue = parseFloat( qtyField.value ) || step; 
qtyField.value = ( currentValue += step );
} 
}
</script>

  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="VLAB_container">
    <header>  
            <div class="VLAB_head">VIRTUAL LABS</div>
            <div class="VLAB_exit">X</div>
            <div class="VLAB_print"></div>      
            <div class="VLAB_audio"></div>
    </header>
<!-- Table Popup -->               
        <div id="VLAB_table" class="VLAB_table"
      style="display:none;z-index:101;">
        <div class="VLAB_table_title">Table <div class="VLAB_table_exit">X</div></div>
        <div class="VLAB_table_subtitle">Title here </div>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <table  id="answered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Value 1</th>
                   <th>Value 2</th>
                   <th>Value 3</th> 
                   <th>Value 4</th>          
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                      <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                      <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                      <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                      <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                      <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                      <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                      <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                      <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                     <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                     <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                     <td data-id="all"><input type='text' value='' /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="VLAB_table_buttons">
         <button type="button" class="btn disabled">Graph</button> 
         <button type="button" class="btn">Save</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn">Print</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Table Popup ENDS-->


<!-- Journal Popup-->
   <div id="VLAB_journal" class="VLAB_journal" style="display:none;z-index:101;">
        <div class="VLAB_journal_title">Journal <div class="VLAB_journal_navigation"><div class="VLAB_journal_exit">X</div>
            <div class="VLAB_journal_next"></div>
            <span class="VLAB_journal_Qno"></span>
            <div class="VLAB_journal_prev"></div>
        </div>
         </div>
        <div class="VLAB_journal_subtitle"></div> 


<div id="journalQuestions" style="display:none;z-index:101;">
<form action="#" class="regform" method="get">
   <p>What part of the digestive system would you see in a cross-section anterior to the gizzard?<br/>
        <textarea class="VLAB_journal_text_area" id="Answer1"
           name="Question1" placeholder=""></textarea></p>
   <p>What structure in the earthworm has a similar function as the human heart? Explain your answer.<br/>
        <textarea class="VLAB_journal_text_area" id="Answer2"
           name="Question2" placeholder=""></textarea></p>
   <p>What do two earthworms exchange during mating? Explain your answer.<br/>
        <textarea class="VLAB_journal_text_area" id="Answer3"
           name="Question3" placeholder=""></textarea></p>
   <p>Describe the difference between a closed and an open circulatory system.<br/>
        <textarea class="VLAB_journal_text_area" id="Answer4"
           name="Question4" placeholder=""></textarea></p>
   <p>Do earthworms have a front and a back end? Explain your answer.<br/>
        <textarea class="VLAB_journal_text_area" id="Answer5"
           name="Question5" placeholder=""></textarea></p>
   <p>What characteristics distinguish an annelid from other worms?<br/>
        <textarea class="VLAB_journal_text_area" id="Answer6"
           name="Question6" placeholder=""></textarea></p>
</form>
</div>

    <div class="VLAB_journal_buttons">
       <button type="button" class="btn">Save</button> 
       <button id="journalPrint" type="button" class="btn">Print</button>
    </div>
   </div>
<!-- Journal Popup ENDS-->
<!-- AUDIO START -->

<div style="display:none;">
<audio preload="metadata" id="a1" class="a1">
    <source class="aud_src" src="assets/audio/sound2drag.mp3" type = "audio/mp3">
    <source class="aud_src" src="assets/audio/sound2drag.ogg" type = "audio/ogg">
</audio>
</div>
<!--  AUDIO END -->

<!-- Calculator -->
    <form>
        <div class="VLAB_CALC">
            <div class="VLAB_CALC_title">Calculator
                <div class="VLAB_CALC_exit">X</div>
            </div>

          <div class="VLAB_CALC_screen">
          <input type="text" id="memory" class="pull-left" value="" readonly /> <input type="text" id="displayPanel" class="pull-right" value="0" readonly /> </div>
            <div class="VLAB_CALC_buttonpad">
                <div class="dark" onclick='ac()'>AC</div>
                <div class="dark" onclick='ce()'>CE/C</div>
                <div class="dark" onclick='perc()' > %</div>
                <div class="dark right" onclick='getoperator("/")'>/</div>
                <div onclick='getdigit("1")'>1</div>
                <div onclick='getdigit("2")'>2</div>
                <div onclick='getdigit("3")'>3</div>
                <div class="dark right" onclick='getoperator("*")'>&times;</div>
                <div onclick='getdigit("4")'>4</div>
                <div onclick='getdigit("5")'>5</div>
                <div onclick='getdigit("6")'>6</div>
                <div class="dark right" onclick='getoperator("+")'>&plus;</div>

                <div onclick='getdigit("7")'>7</div>
                <div onclick='getdigit("8")'>8</div>
                <div onclick='getdigit("9")'>9</div>
                <div class="dark right" onclick='getoperator("-")'>&minus;</div>

                <div onclick='getdigit("0")'>0</div>
                <div class="dark" onclick='v(".")'>.</div>
                <div class="dark right equal-sign" onclick='e()'>=</div>


                <div class="dark lastrow" onclick='sto()' >STO</div>
                <div class="dark lastrow" id="memoryBtn" onclick='rcl()'>RCL</div>
                <div class="dark right lastrow" onclick=' sum_m()'>SUM</div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<!-- Calculator END -->


    <div id="VLAB_leftPanel" class="VLAB_leftPanel">
        <div class="VLAB_leftPanel_head">Measurements</div>
        <div class="VLAB_leftPanel_subhead">What are the structures and body systems of an earthworm?</div>
        <div class="VLAB_leftPanel_content">
           <p>We study earthworms to learn the structures and functions of segmented worms, also called annelids. Segmentation supports diversified functions of body parts and tissues. Studying the anatomy and body systems of annelids helps us understand the bodies of higher-level organisms. <br/><br/>Earthworms are classified in the phylum <i>Annelida</i>. (Kingdom: Animal; Phylum; Annelida; Class: Oligochaeta; Order: Opisthopora; Family: Lumbricidae; Genus: <i>Lumbricus</i>; Species:<i>Lumbricus terrestris</i>) The Annelida also include leeches and bristleworms. Segmented worms have bilateral symmetry and have a coelom, which is a fluid-filled body cavity surrounded by mesoderm. Earthworms have two body openings, a mouth and an anus. The basic body plan of segmented worms consists of a digestive tract within a tube. Earthworms are hermaphrodites, which means that an individual animal produces both sperm and eggs. During mating, two earthworms exchange sperm. Each earthworm forms a capsule for the eggs and sperm in which the eggs are fertilized. The capsule is left behind in the soil where the young earthworms emerge from the eggs in two to three weeks. Earthworms are herbivores. They obtain food by eating through the soil and extracting nutrients from it as food passes through the digestive tract. As an earthworm burrows, it loosens, aerates, and fertilizes the soil. Earthworm burrows provide passageways for plant roots and improve drainage of the soil.<br/><br/>
           <b>Procedure</b><br/><br/> <b>1</b>. Click the <b>Lab manual</b> to read about earthworm anatomy.<br/><br/><b>2</b>. Click the <b>External anatomy button</b> to view a diagram of the external features of an earthworm.<br/><br/><b>3</b>. Drag and drop the <b>Labels</b> to the matching structures of the illustration.<br/><br/><b>4</b>. When all structures are labeled, the <b>Check button</b> is enabled. Click the <b>Check button</b> to receive feedback on whether the labels are matched with the correct structures. Correct the highlighted incorrect labels.<br/><br/><b>5</b>. Click the <b>Internal anatomy button</b> to view a diagram of the internal features of the earthworm and repeat steps 3 and 4.<br/><br/><b>6</b>. Answer the <b>Journal Questions</b>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="VLAB_leftPanel_buttons">  
               <button id="journalBtn" type="button" class="btn">Journal</button> 
               <button id="calcBtn" type="button" class="btn">Calculator</button>
               <button id="tableBtn" type="button" class="btn">Table</button>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- right Panel  for Interactivity part-->

<div class="VLAB_rightPanel">

   <div id="page_content">
       <div id="vlab_assets">

<!-- for development  -->

<div calss="lab"><img height="683" width="700" src="assets/img/main.png" alt="image" style="position:absolute;"/></div>

<div style="position:absolute;margin-left:12px;margin-top:101px;"><img height="545" width="667" src="assets/img/bg_yellow.png" alt="image" style="position:absolute;"/></div>

<button id="me1" class="button">Hydrogen</button>
<button id="me2" class="button" style="margin-left:184px;">Hydrogen</button>
<button id="me3" class="button" style="margin-left:348px;">Hydrogen</button>
<button id="me4" class="button" style="margin-left:512px;width:160px;">Hydrogen</button>

<!--a class="term" id="pop1"><button class="buttona" style="margin-top:113px;margin-left:530px;width:122px;height:30px;">Show Labels</button></a-->

<script language="javascript">
var _0xd7e2=["\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68","\x75\x73\x65\x72\x41\x67\x65\x6E\x74","\x74\x6F\x75\x63\x68\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x6E\x6F\x43\x6F\x6E\x66\x6C\x69\x63\x74","\x68\x69\x64\x65","\x2E\x41\x6E\x73\x5F\x31\x50\x6F\x70","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65","\x73\x70\x61\x6E","\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E","\x2E\x41\x6E\x73\x5F\x31","\x76\x61\x6C","\x53\x68\x6F\x77","\x48\x69\x64\x65","\x62\x69\x6E\x64","\x23\x62\x74\x6E\x53\x68\x6F\x77","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"];var what=(navigator[_0xd7e2[1]][_0xd7e2[0]](/iPad/i))?_0xd7e2[2]:_0xd7e2[3];var $=jQuery[_0xd7e2[4]]();$(document)[_0xd7e2[16]](function (_0xf214x3){$(_0xd7e2[6])[_0xd7e2[5]]();$(_0xd7e2[15])[_0xd7e2[14]](what,function (_0xf214x3){var _0xf214x4=$(this);$(_0xd7e2[10])[_0xd7e2[9]](_0xd7e2[8])[_0xd7e2[7]]();_0xf214x4[_0xd7e2[11]](_0xf214x4[_0xd7e2[11]]()==_0xd7e2[12]?_0xd7e2[13]:_0xd7e2[12]);} );} );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<div class="Ans_1" style="position:absolute;margin-top:160px;margin-left:23px;opacity:1;">
<span style="opacity:1;" class="Ans_1Pop" ><img height="410" width="490" src="assets/img/label.png" alt="image"/></span>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show Labels" style="position:absolute;margin-top:113px;margin-left:530px;width:122px;height:30px;" />


<form id="f1" style="position:absolute;">
<p><input class="form-control transparent-input" type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='0' readonly='readonly'  style="position:absolute;font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;margin-top:295px;margin-left:240px;width:55px;height:40px;border:black;background:black;color:white;text-align:center;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='add' value='' style="margin-top:277px;margin-left:317px;position:absolute;width:20px;height10px;opacity:0;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='subtract' value='' style="margin-top:305px;margin-left:317px;position:absolute;width:20px;height10px;opacity:0;"/></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
with( document.getElementById( 'f1' ) )
incrementButtons( add, subtract, qty );
</script>

<form id="f2" style="position:absolute;">
<p><input class="form-control transparent-input" type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='0' readonly='readonly'  style="position:absolute;font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;margin-top:350px;margin-left:240px;width:55px;height:40px;border:black;background:black;color:white;text-align:center;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='add' value='' style="position:absolute;margin-top:347px;margin-left:317px;width:20px;height:20px;opacity:0;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='subtract' value='' style="position:absolute;margin-top:369px;margin-left:317px;width:20px;height:20px;opacity:0;"/></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
with( document.getElementById( 'f2' ) )
incrementButtons( add, subtract, qty );
</script>

<button id="check" class="buttona" style="margin-top:494px;margin-left:535px;width:102px;height:30px;">Check</button>

<form id="f3" style="position:absolute;">
<p><input class="form-control transparent-input" type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='0' readonly='readonly'  style="position:absolute;font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;margin-top:574px;margin-left:342px;width:55px;height:40px;border:black;background:black;color:white;text-align:right;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='add' value='' style="position:absolute;margin-top:571px;margin-left:407px;width:12px;height:12px;opacity:0;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='subtract' value='' style="position:absolute;margin-top:586px;margin-left:407px;width:12px;height:12px;opacity:0;"/></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
with( document.getElementById( 'f3' ) )
incrementButtons( add, subtract, qty );
</script>

<form id="f4" style="position:absolute;">
<p><input class="form-control transparent-input" type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='0' readonly='readonly'  style="position:absolute;font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;margin-top:574px;margin-left:428px;width:55px;height:40px;border:black;background:black;color:white;text-align:right;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='add' value='' style="position:absolute;margin-top:571px;margin-left:493px;width:12px;height:12px;opacity:0;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='subtract' value='' style="position:absolute;margin-top:586px;margin-left:493px;width:12px;height:12px;opacity:0;"/></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
with( document.getElementById( 'f4' ) )
incrementButtons( add, subtract, qty );
</script>

<form id="f5" style="position:absolute;">
<p><input class="form-control transparent-input" type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='0' readonly='readonly'  style="position:absolute;font-family:verdana;font-weight:bold;margin-top:574px;margin-left:513px;width:55px;height:40px;border:black;background:black;color:white;text-align:right;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='add' value='' style="position:absolute;margin-top:572px;margin-left:580px;width:12px;height:12px;opacity:0;"/></p>
<p><input type='button' name='subtract' value='' style="position:absolute;margin-top:586px;margin-left:580px;width:12px;height:12px;opacity:0;"/></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
with( document.getElementById( 'f5' ) )
incrementButtons( add, subtract, qty );
</script>


<div id="basic-modal-content" style="position:absolute;margin-top:221px;margin-left:132px;z-index:0;">
<img width="395" height="320" src="assets/img/video1.png" alt="image" />
</div>

<input type="button" id="video" class="buttona" style="margin-top:596px;margin-left:61px;width:80px;height:31px;" value="Video" />

<div id="video" style="position:absolute;margin-top:227px;margin-left:165px;z-index:1;">
<video id="video1" width="330" height="294" autoplay>
  <source src="assets/audio/E20.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="assets/audio/E20.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="assets/audio/E20.webm" type="video/webm" />
  Your browser does not support the video element.
</video></div>

<button id="reset" class="buttona" style="margin-top:596px;margin-left:184px;width:80px;height:31px;">Reset</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</div><!--End VLab Container-->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show some code. It is not clear what you're asking

Comment: No Idea about "Incomplete job/Work". But this surely is an "Incomplete Post". Please Rephrase your question,with some codes.

Comment: (1) FindBugs is a tool that checks java code. Always worth seeing it in action. (2) Comments with TODO and FIXME will be listed. `Window / Action Items - Ctrl 6`

Answer (score 0):

Unless the "incomplete work" / "incomplete job" is something that won't compile OR is flagged in the source code with "FIX ME" or "TO DO" tags (or the like), then I don't see how NetBeans or any other tool could distinguish between what is incomplete, and what is not.

There are tools that can detect some kinds of bug by analysing the source code, but I don't expect that that is what you mean by "incomplete".